# Посчитать сумму каждого числа в строке js

Tags: javascript, числа

На входе: 231 4234 27

На выходе: 231(6) 4234(13) 27(9)

Comment: Ваши попытки какие?

Comment: @Nikita Yudin, 1. Вопрос должен быть в форме вопроса. А не как задача. Обязательно ознакомьтесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 2. Относитесь уважительно к пользователям портала. 3. Обязательно выкладывайте то, что пробовали делать сами. Это не портал выполнения задач на заказ! Так как Вы новый участник - в качестве исключения добавил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходную задачу можно свести к замене каждого числа в строке на что-то.

Для замены можно воспользоваться методом [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), данный метод может принимать в качестве первого параметра регулярное выражение.

Число может соответствовать регулярному выражению `\d+`, выбирающему последовательность цифр.

Для замены всех вхождений нужно указать флаг `g` у регулярного выражения.

---

Далее нужно определиться на что конкретно будет заменено найденное число. Из примера вывода можно заметить, что число меняется само на себя, с добавлением в скобках некоторого числа.

Число в скобках можно получить, если из числа взять все цифры и свернуть с помощью суммы. Для операции свертки можно воспользоваться методом [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Для сборки конечной строки можно воспользоваться [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

В итоге код может принять следующий вид:

```js
console.log("231 4234 27".replace(/\d+/g, $0 => `${$0}(${$0.match(/\d/g).reduce((a,b)=>+a+ +b)})`))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function count(str) {
  return str.split(' ')
    .reduce((res, item) => {
      const sum = item.split('').map(i => +i).reduce((r, s) => r + s, 0)
      return [...res, `${item}(${sum})`];
    }, [])
    .join(' ');
}

console.log(count('231 4234 27'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var z = "231 4234 27";
    var bz = z.split(' ');
    var Arr = [];
    bz.forEach(function (a,b) {
        var tempZ = a.split('');
        var summ = "";
        tempZ.forEach(function (b) {
            summ = +summ + +b;
        });
        Arr[b] = a+'('+summ+')';
    });
    let result = Arr.join(' ');

    console.log(result);
```